# Can't Build apk for release in flutter showing this error

Tags: flutter, dart

when I try to build APK for releases in flutter it is showing these error, and I changed some code that says on [flutter release doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release). I followed all these step twice, but still showing error, don't know why, here is the codes that I changed, some more items I changed too, but I think these cods are contained the error. if any other code needed please comment

error notes :

```
[ +999 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +6 ms] * What went wrong:
[  +68 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
[   +7 ms] > java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
D:\Documents\FLUTTER\Projects\money_manager\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\
armeabi-v7a\AndroidManifest.xml: The process cannot access the file because it is being used 
by another process.
```

**here is the code for style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**build.gradle in app**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "io.msl.moneymanager"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
}
```

**key.properties**

```
storePassword=12345678
keyPassword=12345678
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=key/upload.jks

//this name and pass is just a test
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try those steps;

flutter clean,

flutter pub get,

flutter build appbundle --release --no-tree-shake-icons

Also you can check this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63357)

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps:-

1.Open flutter terminal

Run following command:-

flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64,

It take few time